# what regex to use for finding backup files?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Here is an example backup file I will be putting in preg_match to find.  I am attempting to find the best regex to only grab these types of files.  It needs to check for "backup" then the date (any date) then the time (any time) username and finish with .tar.gz

> backup-12.9.2012_00-00-06_username.tar.gz

As of now, I have the following which works however I am looking for it to be more specific so I dont mistakenly pull something else.

```
preg_match('/backup-[0-9].*_username/', $file)
```

of course "username" will be a php variable when done

Comment: Hi Taylor, I edited your title, you already use the tag `php`, no need to specify it in the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[0-9]` is one digit.

`.*` is any sequence of characters.

So `/backup-[0-9].*_username/` will also match, for example, `backup-1ABCD EFGH_username`

What you probably mean is

```
backup-[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{4}_[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}_username
```

or, to be a bit more loose,

```
backup-[0-9.-_]+username
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem some time ago and here is the function I wrote to do the job (slightly modified for the format that you use):

```
function is_backup($filename, $hour24 = TRUE)
{
    // If the filename is not a compressed tarball then it is not a backup
    if (strcasecmp('.tar.gz', substr($filename, -7)) !== 0)
        return FALSE;

    // The various formats
    $day    = '(?:[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])';
    $month  = '(?:[1-9]|1[012])';
    $year   = '2\d{3}';
    $hour   = ($hour24 ? '(?:0?\d|1\d|2[0-4])' : '(?:0?\d|1[0-2])(?:am|pm)?');
    $minute = $second = '(?:0?\d|[1-5]\d|60)';
    $user   = '[^\.]+';

    // Construct the regular expression
    $regex = "/^backup-{$month}\.{$day}\.{$year}_{$hour}-{$minute}-{$second}_{$user}\.tar\.gz$/i";

    // preg_match returns "1" if it matches
    return preg_match($regex, $filename) === 1;
}
```

If your file names always use leading zeros, where applicable, then you can also just use `fnmatch()` to make an approximate match. It uses shell patterns instead of regular expressions.

```
$pattern = 'backup-??.??.????_??-??-??_*.tar.gz';
$filename = 'backup-12.09.2012_00-00-06_username.tar.gz';
var_dump(fnmatch($pattern, $filename));
```

If you are already rummaging around the file system then the `glob()` function may be more convenient. It basically does the same as `fnmatch()`, but instead of feeding it filenames one-by-one it uses the directory that you are currently in.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with simple [glob](http://php.net/glob)s - no need for a full-blown regex here.

What you need are these two (thanks to the one-digit month which is a WTF on its own that should be fixed to always use two-digit values):

- `backup-??.?.????_??-??-??_username.tar.gz`
- `backup-??.??.????_??-??-??_username.tar.gz`

Possibly you also need to add two cases for single-digit days. Or, as suggested before, always use proper dd.mm.yyyy dates.

Anyway, if you really want to use a regex:

```
^backup-\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}.\d{4}_\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}_username\.tar\.gz$
```

Answer (score 0):

The following expression works, provided the number of digits is the same in all files.

```
preg_match('/backup-[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]\.[0-9]{4}_[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}_username\.tar\.gz/')
```

Or using `\d` to mean a digit:

```
preg_match('/backup-\d\d\.\d\.\d\d\d\d_\d\d-\d\d-\d\d_username\.tar\.gz/')
```

Answer (score 0):

If all the stuff between 'backup' and '_username' is date/time related, is suggest keeping it simple and not needing to change the regex when you change date formats. Simply allow digits and punctuation:

```
/backup-[0-9.:-_]+_[a-zA-Z_-]+\.tar\.gz/
```

the `[0-9.:-_]+` bit will grab any digity-date-ish section. Then `[a-zA-Z_-]+` will grab the username.